# Will a GPU show up in the device manager if it is not connected to the PSU?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu, device-manager

Supposing all Hardware parts are working properly, would the GPU show up inside the device Manager if I plugged it into the PCIe Slot of the Motherboard without connecting the GPU to the PSU?

In case the answer requires a specific Hardware, here are my specifications:

- MOBO: P8B75 M-LX
- PSU: Coba 650Watt Bronze 80 plus
- GPU: msi R9 290x gaming 4GB

Comment: Is there a reason you have connected your GPU to the power supply? Are you having specific issues?

Comment: my GPU does not show up in the device Manager, so I was told either the GPU or the PCIe of the Mobo could be broken. I wanted to collect more possibilities if there are any further. So, I imagined if a third possibility of why the GPU doesnt show up could be the lack of a Connection to the PSU.

Comment: Does your GPU have a power connector on it? This should be relatively obvious, and if it isn't, the installation instructions for the card should note whether or not this connection is necessary.

Comment: yes, it has two connectors, one with 6, one with 8 Pins.

Comment: So you installed the graphics card and did not connect it to your power supply? Why? The card clearly requires it and to expect it to function without a power connection is.... an interesting thought.

Comment: no,it is connected to a PSU, but since it does not show up in the device Manager, i was told, either the GPU itself is broken or the PCIe Slot where it is plugged in.

Comment: I asked this question to understand, whether there could be a third possiblitly for the gpu not showing up in the device Manager, namely no Connection to the psu. So, I asked hypothetically, because maybe the Connection to the psu  is broken.

Comment: Super User is poorly equipped to handle hypothetical questions. If your GPU is connected to your PSU then the question is moot. If the rest of the system is functioning properly then the power supply is probably working correctly. If you are asking for assistance determining why your GPU isn't working, the answer you have already received is the correct answer.

Comment: I admit my wording is suggesting to much hypotheticality, i will post another more specific, question related to this.

Comment: Recommendation: edit this question.

Comment: There are downsides as a low rep account to deleting your questions. Fix them, change them, then you won't have those downsides counting against you.

Comment: thx, i will sleep over and think how to improve it without making it worse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the GPU. I do not have a MSI R9 for testing. Even if I did, I wouldn't unplug the power connectors for your question.

I know that Nvidia Quadro series (K2000 thru to the M10 tesla cards) do - they just won't let Windows know if there's a monitor attached; but it shows in device manager (assuming you can access via another display or RDP). If you run Nvidia's Control panel or the CLI tools it'll actually prompt you that the card is not properly powered.

It is logical that the card behave in unexpected ways. It may not detect at all, it may detect as device which is expecting a firmware update, or it might detect as a display adapter but just not output a picture. **To answer your question in 1 line: yes, it is a possibility that your PSU connectors aren't working properly and that's why the GPU isn't working properly.**

The internet does have reports of cards breaking themselves by not plugging in the correct power so exercise caution. Personally I'm doubtful these reports are real.